# Reason behind cohesive and adhesive force

Tags: electromagnetism, forces, physical-chemistry

What is the real cause behind the cohesive and adhesive forces?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Waals_force the Van der Waals force(s)

Comment: @annav what is london dispersion force?

Comment: In the link above there exists a link for your question. The highlighted words are links: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/London_dispersion_force , it "is a weak intermolecular force arising from quantum induced instantaneous polarization multipoles in molecules. They can therefore act between molecules without permanent multipole moments."

Answer (score 2):

Most molecules have a dipole moment, and are called "polar". This means that the electronsare not uniformly distributed throughout; rather there are some areas with a net positive charge (due to lack of electrons), and some with a net negative charge (due to abundance of electrons). Even water is polar; the electrons in the O-H bond are closer to the oxygen molecule, giving oxygen a slightly negative charge.

Now, the force of attraction between dipoles is what makes up[Van Der Waals forces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Waals_force). Cohesion and adhesion are places where this force crops up.

Note that not all molecules are polar. Apolar ones can acquire a temporary "induced" charge like so:

[image]

This leads to dipole-induced dipole attraction. There also are induced dipole-indiced dipole interactions, when two apolar molecules form extremely temporary dipoles, and line up.